# Excel Make a string based upon values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm facing the following problem:

I have eleven columns of that represent product origins, sometimes the product is taken from one origin and sometimes it is taken from two origins. The columns have values in them that correspond to a fraction of how much is used of that origin. Example (only using 4 origins for ease of example):

```
NTH LGL MSV NIE

{1   0   0   0;

0.5  0   0.5 0; 

0    1   0   0;}
```

The results that I want are then for the first row NTH, for the second row NTH-MSV and for the third row LGL.

I tried using the following formula, but I can't get excel to concatenate the empty cells or errors.

```
=CONCATENATE(IFERROR(OFFSET(AP1;0;IF(AQ4:BA4>0;COLUMN(AQ4:BA4)-COLUMN(AP4);""));""))
```

AQ1 to BA1 contain the product origins and the columns below contain the values (ranging from 0 to 1).

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate only the cells in a row that have non zero value as a final output? Some sort of Conditional Concatenate?

Comment: What should the output in the cell be? The numbers added together, or written out (eg, "0.5, 0.5")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following clarification, try this custom function:

```
Function HEADERFOROVERZERO(rng As Range)
Dim rngCell, returnString: returnString = ""
For Each rngCell In rng
    If (IsNumeric(rngCell.Value)) Then
        If (rngCell.Value > 0) Then
            returnString = returnString & Cells(1, rngCell.Column).Value & "-"
        End If
    End If
Next
If (Len(returnString) > 1) Then
    returnString = Left(returnString, Len(returnString) - 1)
End If
HEADERFOROVERZERO = returnString
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I would like the result to be the origin of the product. So in your example for the first row NTH.

Comment: @Michthan Ahh, so the column header?

Comment: @Michthan Amended my answer - is this what you wanted?

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks. I'm going to implement it in a few hours because it's busy here now, so i'll come back to you if it works!